# Projection from a linear subspace

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space, projection

I have a fairly simple question about the projection from a linear subnspace in $\mathbb{P}^n$. Following Shafarevich, let $E = \{L_1 = ... = L_{n-r} = 0\}$ be a $r$ - dimensional linear subspace in $\mathbb{P}^n$ with $L_1,...,L_{n-r}$ linearly independent linear functionals. The the projection with center $E$ is defined as $\pi_L : \mathbb{P}^n-L\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^{n-r-1}$, $x\mapsto (L_1(x):...:L_{n-r}(x))$.

The geometric interpretation is supposed to be as follows: Given $E$ and a $n-r-1$ - dimensional subspace $H$ disjoint from $E$ and $x\in \mathbb{P}^n-E$, then there is a unique $r+1$ - dimensional subspace $L_x = \langle E,x \rangle$ through $E$ and $x$ that intersects $H$ in exactly one point, which is given by $\pi_L(x)$.

Here is my problem: I can see why the intersection $L_q\cap H$ is a one dimensional affine subspace, i.e. a point in $\mathbb{P}^n$. But I don't see why it equals $\pi_L(x)= (L_1(x):...:L_{n-r}(x))$.

Comment: Can you see what's happening in the simplest case where you're projecting from $[0:\cdots:0:1]$ to $x_n=0$?

Comment: Yes, I do. Then $L = \{x_0 = ... = x_{n-1} = 0\}$, $H = \{x_n = 0\}$ and let $x=(x_0:...:x_n)\notin L$. Then $L_x = \{ (\lambda_1x_0:...:\lambda_1x_{n-1}:\lambda_1x_n+\lambda_2)\text{ }|\text{ }\lambda_1,\lambda_2\in\mathbb{R}\}$ and $L_x\cap H = \{ (\lambda_1x_0:...:\lambda_1x_{n-1}:0)\} = \{(x_0:...:x_{n-1}:0)\}$ and this is exactly $\pi_L(x)$.

Comment: I also have no problem proving the same thing for $L= \{ x_0 = ... = x_{n-r} = 0\}$ and $H= \{ x_{n-r+1} = ... = x_n=0\}$. The latter is actual the general case after choosing a certain basis. But for some reason I wanted to get this insight without choosing a basis...